# How to update multiselect dropdown array in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-update

I am using **multiselect** dropdown in my project. Now I want to update multiselect drop down array value in my mysql Database. I successfully added the multiselect values in database but when I am trying to update I got wrong result. For example if values in array are like this **Array([0]=>A [1]=>B)** and I run a loop to update values in DB then updated values are always with 2nd value of array **(e.g [1]=>B)**. I don't know where is the Problem Kindly help.. Below is my code..

**HTML**

```
<select name="countries[]" id="countries" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Which countries did you sell your products in *" required>
<option value="" disabled="disabled" selected>Which countries did you sell your products in *</option>
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
<option value="Albania">Albania</option>
<option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
<option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
<option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
<option value="Angola">Angola</option>
<option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
```

**PHP**

```
$countries = $_POST['countries'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$size=sizeof($countries);
for($i=0;$i<$size;){
    $count = $trade_info->update_supplier_last_financial_count($user_id, $countries[$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

**Function (update_supplier_last_financial)**

```
public function update_supplier_last_financial_count($user_id,$last_count){

    $db = db::getInstance();    
    $pdo = $db->getConnection();

    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE supplier_last_financial_countries SET countries = :last_count WHERE user_id = :user_id ");

        $stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":last_count", $last_count);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;   
    }

    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You for loop would be `for($i=0;$i<$size;$i++){` and remove `$i++` inside loop

Comment: @Saty.. Thanks for reply but it's not working. same result..

Comment: Have you got any error???

Comment: @Saty I am not getting any error but wrong result. It is always updated the DB with 2nd value of array not both. Thanks.

Comment: Do save countries in DB with comma Separated ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query is updating the same row over and over again. It's limited by a `WHERE` but the condition of the `WHERE` (`$user_id`) never changes.

Something like this might work:

```
$countries = $_POST['countries'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    $count = $trade_info->update_supplier_last_financial_count($user_id, $country);
}

public function update_supplier_last_financial_count($user_id,$last_count) {
    $db = db::getInstance();    
    $pdo = $db->getConnection();

    try {
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM supplier_last_financial_countries WHERE user_id = :user_id ");
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO supplier_last_financial_countries SET countries = :last_count, user_id = :user_id ");
        $stmt->bindparam(":user_id", $user_id);
        $stmt->bindparam(":last_count", $last_count);
        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt;   
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you are correct it always updating the same row again and again!!

Comment: @miken32 thanks for reply. Then How I update the multiselect array values in DB for same $user_id ?? Thanks.

Comment: @Saty Then how should I update with same $user_id with both array values? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to store multiple countries in a column, you should store them as a set(i.e. comma separated values in a string). Try this.

```
  $countries = $_POST['countries'];
  $user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
  $countriesValues = implode(',', $countries);//store country values as a set
  $count = $trade_info->update_supplier_last_financial_count($user_id, $countriesValues);
```

For this, you need to change datatype from `int` to `varchar`
You can also update the countries value in the same way.